# tar command not found when setting up docker container, mac m1 chip

Tags: docker, apple-m1, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to set up a dev container in visual studio code. I have a Mac m1 pro and have attempted to account for the arm architecture. Stumped as to be what the error is as no way of installing tar seems to work.

files are

devcontainer.json

```
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
    "context": ".",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "runArgs": ["--env-file",".docker.test.env"],
    "extensions": ["ms-python.python"]
}
```

DockerFile

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 amazonlinux:2

ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
RUN echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf

RUN amazon-linux-extras enable python3.8 epel postgresql11 && \
    yum clean metadata && yum install -y epel-release && \
    yum install -y tar.x86_64 && \
    poppler libxml2 freexl xerces-c
```

the errors thrown are

```
/bin/sh: line 10: tar: command not found
Exit code 127
Stop (55 ms): Run in container: (dd iflag=fullblock bs=8192 count=6254 2>/dev/null; dd iflag=fullblock bs=3089 count=1 2>/dev/null) | tar --no-same-owner -xz -C /vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/e7e037083ff4455cf320e344325dacb480062c3c_1696808824503
Start: Run in container: rm -rf /vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/e7e037083ff4455cf320e344325dacb480062c3c_1696808824503
Stop (375 ms): Run in container: /bin/sh
Stop (113 ms): Installing VS Code Server
Command in container failed: (dd iflag=fullblock bs=8192 count=6254 2>/dev/null; dd iflag=fullblock bs=3089 count=1 2>/dev/null) | tar --no-same-owner -xz -C /vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/e7e037083ff4455cf320e344325dacb480062c3c_1696808824503
/bin/sh: line 10: tar: command not found
Exit code 127
```

Comment: Is this error shown when building the container, or when running it?

Comment: when running the container. Using 'open current folder in container' on vs code

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem off and on for years. I always have to restart my machine for it to work.